# single asp.net web form displayed in two frames

Tags: css, asp.net

the webform gets displayed in two frames instead of one...

```
<body style="background-repeat:no-repeat " background="ProjectImages/back.jpg">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="31px" BackColor="#33CCFF" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" >
        <div class="style2">
            &nbsp;<span class="style1">Read</span></div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

i want it be displayed in one frame with a single background image covering the whole frame.
It is producing  scroll bar unnecessarily..

Comment: Try background-size:cover;

Comment: @Richa

no effect..generating following error
background-size is not a known css property

Comment: Put background-image instead of background and then use background-size:cover;

Comment: or somethinglike this                                      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

Comment: @Richa...still not working..the image is not displayed in  this case..